# Automatically crop a scan of multiple photos?

Tags: images, photography, image-editing, scanning

I am looking for a decent scanner software that will allow:

- Automatically crop a scan of multiple photos (Approx 4 photos every scan)
- Re-orientation
- Scratch and dust removal (if possible)
- Color correction
- Red-eye removal

I have about 1000 of old photos to scan. If all that can be done by a single software.. it will be time saving!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (Free, open source, cross-platform, CLI) to post-process all your scanned images at once:

- Automatically crop a scan of multiple photos, aka. [multicrop](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php)
- [red-eye removal](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/redeye/index.php)
- [auto-orientation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8100)
- [Color Correction](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#cdl)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). It is a free and lightweight graphics viewer with a batch conversion tool. You can find the option under the `File` menu or by using the shortcut key <kbd>B</kbd>. Then click the `Advanced` button for more options.

[image]

You can either manually set a `CROP` region (top left), or choose the `Auto crop borders` option which only works on white and transparent background. There are also options to resize and re-orient the image. However, it does not have an option for batch red-eye removal, and it can only fix one image at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We recently put together this video for our clients entitled [Tech Tips: Ways to Split Multiple Images Scanned on a Flatbed Scanner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tk4EBagMvc) that may be of some help.

As far as the image restoration components, the newly released [Vivid-Pix Restore](http://www.vivid-pix.com/restore.html) application does this with typically with a single click.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  Do you have any association with Vivid-Pix Restore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Photoshop CS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop) (Non-free, Windows / Mac, scriptable):

- scan, e.g. with [TWAIN](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/twain-plug-photoshop-cs4-cs5.html)
- Automatically crop a scan of multiple photos, aka. [multicrop](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/crop-straighten/)
- red-eye removal
- [auto-orientation](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/crop-straighten/)
- Color Correction